# Wordpress: disable scheduled posts / publish posts immediately

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there a way to disable the functionality of having a scheduled post / post in the fututre programmatically for every post on the entire website?

I have only found answers on this (code for functions.php or plugins such as "The Future is now") from like 5-6 years ago, which apparently do not work anymore.

Answer (score 3):

You could remove the action `_future_post_hook` in your functions.php file:

```
<?php
function onetarek_prevent_future_type( $post_data ) {
     if ( $post_data['post_status'] == 'future' && $post_data['post_type'] == 'post' )
     {
          $post_data['post_status'] = 'publish';
     }
     return $post_data;
}
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 'onetarek_prevent_future_type');
remove_action('future_post', '_future_post_hook');
?>
```

Source: https://onetarek.com/wordpress/publish-a-wordpress-post-with-a-future-date/